# How to start pthread inside class constructor on member function of same class?

Tags: c++, multithreading, class, pthreads

I am trying to make

```
ThreadPool::ThreadPool(int num_workers) {
    workers.reserve(num_workers);

    for (int i = 0; i < num_workers; i++) {
        pthread_create(&workers[i], NULL, threadLoop, NULL);
    }
}
```

`void* threadLoop (void*);` this is threadLoop declaration, it's private member function of ThreadPool class, when I compile, I get an error `invalid use of non-static member function` I tried to make function static, but then it can't see other variable declared inside the class. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Use std::thread.

Comment: I have to use pthread, unfortunately

Comment: Then you have to learn how to use a C API unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pthreads uses a C-based API and so it can only use free-standing functions for thread procedures, not *non-static* class methods. A *non-static* class method has a hidden `this` parameter that pthreads doesn't know about.

However, you can declare `threadLoop` as *static* instead (to remove the `this` parameter), and then pass the class's `this` pointer to `threadLoop` in its user-defined argument.

Also, you need to `resize()` your `workers` container, not `reserve()` it. `reserve()` preallocates the container's internal memory, but it does not add new elements (only the `capacity()` changes, not the `size()`). Using `operator[]` to access elements that have not actually been added to the container is *undefined behavior*.

Try this instead:

```
class ThreadPool
{
private:
    std::vector<pthread_t> workers;
    static void* threadLoop (void *arg);
public:
    ThreadPool(int num_workers);
    ...
};

ThreadPool::ThreadPool(int num_workers)
{
    workers.resize(num_workers);
    for (int i = 0; i < num_workers; i++) {
        pthread_create(&workers[i], NULL, threadLoop, this);
    }
}

void* ThreadPool:threadLoop (void *arg)
{
    ThreadPool *pThis = (ThreadPool*) arg;
    // use pThis as needed... 
}
```

Technically speaking, using a *non-static class method* as a free-standing function is also *undefined behavior*, but it works fine in most compilers, and there are plenty of libraries that are designed around that functionality. If in doubt, you can always define an actual free-standing function, and make it a `friend` of your class if it needs to access non-public members.